# Multiple PHP-FPM versions on Amazon Linux load the same config

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, nginx

I want to run multiple PHP-FPM Versions on a Server with Amazon Linux.
The Setup runs with Nginx and the configuration there is fine.
I installed PHP 5.6 and 7.1 and modified the /etc/php-fpm-5.6/www.conf and the /etc/php-fpm-7.1/www.conf to create a pool for each version.
The Problem is that when I start one of the fpm services they always load the socket information out of the /etc/php-fpm.conf and don't use the version specific one.
I didn't modify the /etc/php-fpm.conf and just changed the listen part in the Version specific ones

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm-7.1.sock
```

and use the socket in my nginx:

```
  fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm-7.1.sock;
```

I couldn't find any advice why this is done. All documentations i found just tell me to to what i have done and it should work.

Comment: how are you starting the php-fpm services?

Comment: Using the service command, so using the scripts in init.d

Comment: Can you make sure they are using the intended executables and two different version PHP-FPM is being actually started? Also I don't see that a `/etc/php-fpm.conf` should exists. Are these version of FPM manually compiled from source or you used some setup script? For me the conf goes to `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf` after installation and there is no `/etc/php-fpm.conf`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed PHP using yum. The php-fpm wasn't removed in this process, but the pool config under `/etc/php-fpm-7.1/www.conf` and the php-fpm config under `/etc/php-fpm-7.1.conf` have been created. When i try to delete `/etc/php-fpm.conf` i'll get an error that its missing at startup. Starting both at the same time is not possible because they try to listen to the same socket because they use the same config.

Comment: I was able to load the specified configs with `php-fpm-5.6 -y /etc/php-fpm-5.6.conf` but this is not permanent. When i restart then the changes are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. The `/etc/php-fpm.conf` is just a symlink that points to the version of PHP you last installed (i.e. both `7.1` and `5.6` end up pointing to `5.6`).

I ended up adding the `-y` flag (you mentioned earlier) to the `/etc/init.d` files, like this:

`/etc/init.d/php-fpm-7.1`:

`daemon --pidfile ${pidfile} /usr/sbin/php-fpm-7.0 -y /etc/php-fpm-7.1.conf  --daemonize $OPTIONS`

And,

`/etc/init.d/php-fpm-5.6`:

`daemon --pidfile ${pidfile} php-fpm-5.6 -y /etc/php-fpm-5.6.conf $OPTIONS`

If you go with this approach, watch out for future yum updates, just in case they overwrite your configuration changes.

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to handle this is to uncomment the last line of `/etc/sysconfig/php-fpm-X.Y` where `X.Y` is the php version, for example `/etc/sysconfig/php-fpm-7.2`

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/php-fpm-7.2
# Additional environment file for php-fpm
# Uncomment below to use the php 7.2 specific configuration file
OPTIONS="-y /etc/php-fpm-7.2.conf"
```